# How to run 2 parfor's in parallel in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I have 2 different parfor's in my script. With different number of iterations but no dependencies.

Is there a simple way that does not require re-writing to make MATLAB run both of them in parallel (with each other)?

Comment: Why would you do that ?

Comment: I have a server with many cores and whenever the 2 loops have no dependency then why not run them in parallel? If there is a direct way that preserves code readability then why not use it?

Comment: Create 2 jobs...

Comment: Ok, but a simple parfor will already use your different cores (if we suppose that your for loop can be linearized). So you're not going to save some time...

Comment: @TheTester Are you using a batch scheduler like PBS or TORQUE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Matt alluded to, the easiest way to do this is involves some rewriting. `parfor` loops inherently take over the whole parallel pool so (as far as I know) you can't do what you're asking.

My preferred way of handling this would be to move the body of each loop into a function and then use [parfeval](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfeval.html]).